# Sending query string value through url using foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am using codeigniter for the application. First,I created the View that consist of Message TextArea Box , DropDownlist which value comes from database, and submit button. I have database of two colums one for mobile number and another for service provider.I have predefined url with query string value (http://www.something.com?mobno=numbervar&msg=messagevar)

In model class, I have function called getProvider1, to get return the array of mobile number of particular provider. I should use the above url with query string passing mobile number and message that inputted by user. Here I have used foreach loop to pass message to different mobile number through query string .

The problem is that I couldn't get idea how to pass message to multiple mobile number without visiting that something.com pages and show result which query string value is passed and which are failed... Here, I couldn't pass the different query string value in that url using foreach. It only visited one page or redirect once....Is there any function something like redirect()....or any other options. Please want some suggestion... will be greatly appreciated.... Following is the controller's function to send message

```
function message()
{               $message = $this->input->post('message');
        $provider = $this->input->post('provider');

        if($provider == 'provider1')
        {
            $number = $this->message_model->getProvider1();
            $mobile = array();
            foreach($number as $no)
            {
                $mobile = $no;

            redirect('http://something.com?mobno='.$mobile.'&msg='.$message);
            }


        }

               else if
                {
                     // same process for service provider2
                }
               else
                {
                  //other service provider
                }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not 100% sure what it is you want to do exactly, but redirect will clearly only work once (since after you have redirected you are no longer on your page).

What you could do, based on my understanding of your code, is look in to [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php). It gives you the opportunity to load several pages and look at their results "behind the scenes" and display whatever you want to your users.

Some other notes.

```
/* Instead of doing the same thing for all provides with IFs, rewrite you message model to take the provider name as a input variable insdead. */
$number = $this->message_model->getProvider($provider);
/* $mobile = array(); // you never use this array, no need for it */
foreach($number as $mobile)
{
  /* $mobile = $no; //completly useless, just name it in the foreach */

  /* --- do a cURL request here --- */
  $curl = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://something.com?mobno='.$mobile.'&msg='.$message);
  $curl_info = curl_getinfo($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  if ($curl_info['http_code'] != 200) /* Handle error if any */
  {
    $errors[] = 'ERROR WITH REQUEST: http://something.com?mobno='.$mobile.'&msg='.$message;
  }
}
```